# Extract elements from html-string in ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, clojurescript

For a `ClojureScript` project I'm looking for a concise way to extract content from an external `HTML` document on the client side. The content is actually received via an ajax call in the `Markdown` format, which is parsed to `HTML` subsequently. So a `HTML` string is the point of departure.

```
(def html-string "<p>Something, that <a>was</a> Markdown before</p>")
```

The libraries `Enlive` and `Garden` for instance use vectors to express CSS Selectors, which are needed here. `Enlive` has a front-end sister, called `Enfocus`, which provides similar semantics.

Here's an `enfocus` example which extracts some content from the current DOM:

```
(require '[enfocus.core :as ef])

(ef/from js/document.head :something [:title]
         (ef/get-text))
;;{:something "My Title"}
```

If there were more matches the value of `:something` would become a vector. I could not figure out, how to apply this function on arbitrary `HTML` strings. The closest I could get was by using this function:

```
(defn html->node [h]
  (doto (.createElement js/document "div")
    (aset "innerHTML" h)))
```

and then:

```
(ef/from (html->node html-string) :my-link [:a]
  (ef/get-text))
;;{:my-link "was"}
```

However, this is not quite clean, since now there's a div wrapping everything, which might cause trouble in some situations.

Comment: Maybe just take the firstChild of your div.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting some HTML content into a `div` makes your arbitrary HTML automatically evaluated. What you should do instead is to parse your HTML string with something like this.

```
(defn parse-html [html]
  "Parse an html string into a document"
  (let [doc (.createHTMLDocument js/document.implementation "mydoc")]
    (set! (.-innerHTML doc.documentElement) html)
    doc
    ))
```

This is plain and simple ClojureScript, maybe using the Google Closure library would be more elegant if you want you can dig into the [goog.dom namespace](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.dom.html) or someplace else inside the Google Closure API.

Then you parse your HTML string:

```
(def html-doc (parse-html "<body><div><p>some of my stuff</p></div></body>"))
```

So you can call Enfocus on your document:

```
(ef/from html-doc :mystuff [:p] (ef/get-text))
```

Result:

```
{:mystuff "some of my stuff"}
```